# Recompiling Ubuntu kernel for MacOSX

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel

I run Ubuntu 18.04 on my Macbook Pro and it runs just fine. During the installation I did select the option to install third party drivers for WiFi, graphics etc if needed.

I'd like to recompile the kernel I have installed. I realize that I can obtain the config of my currently installed kernel from `/boot/config-*`, and that I can get the kernel source by doing `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`.

However, I'm guessing this repository does not fetch the third party drivers for WiFi, graphics etc. What would be the easiest way to build a kernel with all these drivers as well? I'd like to be able to build, install and use a similar version of the kernel before I attempt to modify it to suit my needs. Is there another repository that I'd need to `apt-get` or `wget`? If so, which repository is it? How can I use that along with the kernel build process?

[EDIT]

I came across the RestrictedModule page [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomRestrictedModules), however the `linux-restricted-modules-common` does not seem to exist for 18.04.

Comment: compiling custom kernels is not supported well here. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer to this. I cloned the repository from `git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git`, copying over the config from my `/boot` directory and building as follows.

```
$ git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git
$ cd ubuntu-bionic
$ cp /boot/config-<something> .config
$ make oldconfig
$ make -j4 deb-pkg
$ cd ..
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```